# Cookie Based Expiration for AJAX Polling Calls

Tags: ajax, polling

I have a use case where I want to log out a user if he hasn't been doing anything for 30 minutes.

When the user logs in a cookie get created and for every other request to the server I am Authenticating based on that Cookie. The expiry time for Cookie is set to 30 minutes and for every request that comes to the server the timeout is increased by 30 min from the current time.

However, I have AJAX call which is automatically done after 30 Seconds. I don't want change the cookie expiry time if that request comes from that AJAX call.

One possible solution is to Set the header and filter them out. But I don't think this is a clean solution.

Comment: When I've done this I've done it server side, keeping a 'future access time' against each user in the database user table. Every time authentication occurs it checks against the time and if it has expired redirects to a log-in page, otherwise it just updates the time in the database to a point 30 minutes in the future. Any cookie use is purely for identification and not time-out. It would be fairly trivial to eliminate a particular script source using this server-side method as you just don't update the database for particular ajax scripts, and also prevents any tampering with cookies etc.